# Grease or anti-seize for alloy thru-axle-to-QR adapter?

Tags: quick-release, through-axle

I've got a 26" front wheel with HB-M758 15x100mm thru-axle hub that I'll be using on a QRx100mm front fork. Going to install my alloy 15mm-to-QR axle adapter, it's a tight fit, which is good. Since the adapter is aluminum and the hub shaft is steel (I think), I'm just wondering if I should use anti-seize to lubricate it rather than standard grease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-seize is the best from the standpoint of corrosion resistance and it has washout resistance that surpasses the greases usually used on bikes. The reasons it's not used on bikes more are that it's messy, another thing to have, and it takes a pretty extreme or specific situation for grease to not be enough. Tradition plays a role too. You can use it here and in all other metal-on-metal assembly prep spots where you'd use grease otherwise. The parts won't mind, but it's up to you whether the messiness is worth it. I would never use it on thru-axle or QR shafts because of the mess factor when the wheel is out.